# How do we know if AWS Fargate spot instance is available?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I'm using below code to launch fargate instances, here I've a doubt what if fargate spot instance not available, does it launch an normal instance by default or raise an exception ??

I went through boto3 docs, I'm not not able to find it.

```py
import boto3

ecs_client = boto3.client('ecs')

# Set the parameters for the task
cluster_name = 'my-cluster'
task_definition = 'my-def'
capacity_provider = 'FARGATE_SPOT'

# Launch the task
response = ecs_client.run_task(
    cluster=cluster_name,
    taskDefinition=task_definition,
    capacityProviderStrategy=[
        {
            "capacityProvider": capacity_provider
        }
    ],
    networkConfiguration={
        'awsvpcConfiguration': {
            'subnets': [
                'subnet-001',
            ],
            'securityGroups': [
                'sg-001',
            ],
            'assignPublicIp': 'ENABLED'
        }
    },
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it will not switch to on-demand instance on `FARGATE` and you will not get any raise exception. You can only see it on service metrics spot capacity not available.

Solution is to combine `FARGATE` and `FARGATE_SPOT` together with weight.

```
capacityProviderStrategy=[
        {
            'capacityProvider': 'FARGATE_SPOT',
            'weight': 4
        },
        {
            'capacityProvider': 'FARGATE',
            'weight': 1
        },
    ]
```

`20%` on `FARGATE` and `80%` on `FARGATE_SPOT`

Comment: cool, if i run 1 task, with the above weightage what happens if fargate_spot doesn't exist?

Comment: It will try to deploy with Fargate